# sublimetext is combining letters

Tags: character, sublimetext3, typing

I am using sublime text 3 portable under ubuntu. I must have hit some sort of shortcut, because all of a sudden, sublime text is combining letters to some sort of arabic language. (As most of the letters are not displaying correctly, I can not tell which language it is). The following should have been visibility:hidden;

```
vしびilちÿひضㄣ;
```

I fiddled around a bit, but I dont know where to start and what to ask.

Edit: It has not neccessary something to do with arabic. For example s+s are combined to ß.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was desperate so I erased

```
/home/username/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/
```

Which kind of worked. I shouldn't have erased all of it, now I get some errors when opening a file. But the typing problem is also gone. If someone else tries this, maybe she should be a bit more careful.